# Microsoft Office "configuration setup" when I start WORD or EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Every time I open Word (or Excel) file, the configuration setup starts:

[image]

(even if it completes, on another run, it still starts again).

Why this happens and how to solve?

Answer (score 7):

Found solution. Instead of **`regedit`** steps, just run this code in **`cmd`** (with admin privilegges):

```
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options" /v "NoRereg" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options" /v "NoRereg" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\PowerPoint\Options" /v "NoRereg" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

and that's all.

Answer (score 5):

This issue can occur if the registry settings have been corrupted.

First off, try to [repair your Office installation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

---

If that fails to fix the issue, an article showcasing the following two solutions can be found [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-ways-get-rid-configuration-progress-window-starting-word/).

**Solution 1** (Registry Mod):

Run regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY-CURRENT-USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options
```

Add a new `DWORD` entry named `NoRereg` with a value of `1`.

Repeat for Excel.

This will work when multiple versions of Office are installed, as well as when only one version is installed.

**Solution 2** (Program Files Mod):

Navigate to the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller\
```

Rename `SETUP.EXE` to anything else, e.g `SETUP_diabled.EXE`.

This will only work for the case where one version of Office is installed.